# How do i access a function trough events sender in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, events, polymer

I have a custom element which fires an event and I also catch it in another element with func:function(event, detail,sender)

My Question is: Can I somehow access the functions of the element which has fired the event? 
I tried it with sender.func() and simliar approaches but I cant find out how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but because you didn't post your code, i cannot say what's wrong with it.

Here is a small complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src='../lib/platform/platform.js'></script>
  <link href="../lib/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
</head>

<body unresolved>

  <polymer-element name="my-button">
    <template>
      <div on-click="{{onClick}}">Click me!</div>
      {{message}}
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer('my-button', {
        onClick: function(){
          this.fire('my-button-fire');
        },
        sayHello: function() {
          this.message = "Hello world!"
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <polymer-element name="my-app">
    <template>
      <my-button on-my-button-fire="{{onFire}}"></my-button>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer('my-app', {
        onFire: function(event, detail, sender){
          sender.sayHello();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <my-app></my-app>

</body>
```

Comment: yes this works, and well, i dont know why i didnt work before but now it does... kinda embarrassing, sorry.